# Customized ClickOnce Installed App Directory

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment

How to change the default directory for app installed with ClickOnce? I mean how to change it for example to "C:\Program Files\CompanyName\Applications\etc.."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the ClickOnce installation directory. If you want this level of control then an MSI (or other deployment technology) is a better fit for you.